# Jquery mobile - Change dynamically data-transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

With jquery mobile transition, I would like my site behaves like an elevator.
I have a vertical menu :

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="menu_item">
        <span class="menu_number">2</span>
    </div>
</a>
<a href="#">
    <div class="menu_item">
       <span class="menu_number">1</span>
    </div>
</a>
<a href="#">
   <div class="menu_item active_item">
        <span class="menu_number">0</span>
   </div>
</a>
```

I set dynamically the data-transition attribute on each page with :

```
$(document).bind("pagechange", function() {
var firstActive = false;
$('.menu_item').each(function( index ) {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active_item') && firstActive == false)
        $(this).parent().attr('data-transition','slidedown');
    else if(!$(this).hasClass('active_item') && firstActive == true)
        $(this).parent().attr('data-transition','slideup');
    else if($(this).hasClass('active_item')){
        firstActive = true;
        $(this).parent().removeAttr('data-transition');
    }
});});
```

Initial state :

- Menu 2 => data-transition="slidedown"
- Menu 1 => data-transition="slidedown"
- Menu 0 => no data-transition

If i click on "1" menu :

- Menu 2 => data-transition="slidedown"
- Menu 1 => no data-transition
- Menu 0 => data-transition="slideup"

Then, if i click on "2" menu :

- Menu 2 => no data-transition
- Menu 1 => data-transition="slideup"
- Menu 0 => data-transition="slideup"

Even if menu 1 has data-transition="slideup", when i click it does a slidedown (initial data-transition)

I don't understand this behaviour.

PS: if i click on menu 0, it does a slideup transition (good behaviour)

Comment: You are looking for the active_item class on the menu_item div, but in markup you put it on the menu_number span.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly clear about the transition behaviour you're expecting on your menu. I once came across the need to dynamically change `data-transition` on my menu. Consider this menu, this time a horizontal one:

```
<div class="menu">
   <a href="#page1" data-transition="slide">First Page</a>
   <a href="#page2" data-transition="slide" class="current_link ui-btn-active">Second Page</a>
   <a href="#page3" data-transition="slide">Third Page</a>      
   <a href="#page4" data-transition="slide">Fourth Page</a>
</div>
```

My requirement was: If the current page is `Second Page`, when I go back to `First Page` (by click/tapping on the menu link), the sliding should be backwards. I achieved this like so:

```
$( document ).on( "pagebeforeshow", function() {
 $('.current_link').prevAll().attr('data-direction', 'reverse');
});
```

I feel that the simple elegance of this solution might be able to help in your situation.
Best of luck.